# Can the word "Retrospective" be a noun?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am a software engineer and I hear many times people use the word "retrospective" as a noun to refer to the sprint retrospective meeting, which is a term introduced from `Agile methodology`. As a non-native English speaker, I am wondering whether this is something grammatically correct or people should actually switch to use the noun "retrospection"

Comment: The full Oxford English Dictionary has the adjectival usage from 1660, and the noun usage from 1789 (B1 *An act of retrospection; a survey or review of past events or experiences;* B2 *An exhibition, programme of music, or similar collection showing the development of a person's work over a period of time*).

Comment: Retrospective can certainly be a noun as FumbleFingers has pointed out, with 2 meanings listed in the OED, but it's not a particularly common noun. Can you explain what you mean by "retrospective"?  I'm not familiar with what Agile methodology is, or which terms are used within it.  Also what is a "sprint retrospective meeting"?

Comment: @BillyKerr It's basically a meeting at which people review recent past events or experience of the work, generally done with a stated intention of learning from those experiences to do things better in future.

Comment: So in that case, meaning No. 1 referenced by FumbleFingers would seem to match your usage.

Comment: I don't see these definitions at all from Oxford Dictionary: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/retrospective_1. Is there an online reference? @FumbleFingers

Comment: I cut&pasted those 2 definitions from the FULL OED, which is online for anyone who pays the $299 subscription (free to me from my local library! :). The B1 definition is a bit obscure, so I can't easily find that on free sites. But [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retrospective) (along with many others) has the equivalent of B2: *a show of the work an artist has done in their life so far*.

Comment: ...but honestly, if one of these "sub-definitions" can't easily be found online for free, I seriously doubt anyone learning English as a foreign language needs to know it!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, *retrospective* can be a noun.

Any time you hear a large group of people consistently and fluently using a word in a certain way you can be confident that it is a correct usage. Incorrect usages are by definition the ones that competent speakers of the relevant language variety avoid.